# How to change default application in Ubuntu in command line?

Tags: command-line, default-programs

[image]

I want to change videos to VLC. I have already installed VLC using `sudo apt-get install vlc`.

I want to get a CLI solution because I am making a script that changes the configuration of a newly installed OS as my own customization.

Comment: Instead of `nano`, of course, use `sed` or `awk`  or your favourite file modification tool to add VLC to it.

Comment: The command-line VLC player (`cvlc`) is started by the command: `cvlc /path/to/video/file`